# error when using delegate array

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, sigabrt, exc-bad-access

I am attempting to create a "Player" object in a differing class by initializing with an array of "Player" objects that I have in my app delegate. This code worked (and still does) with ios 4.3, but crashes (SIGABRT or exec_bad_access) with ios 5.0.

I have imported the app delegate.

Here is the code that fails:

```
PlaybookAppDelegate *delegate = (PlaybookAppDelegate *)
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
Player *thisPlayer = [delegate.players objectAtIndex:index.row];
```

Here is the declaration in my AppDelegate:

```
@interface PlaybookAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    NSMutableArray *players;   
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *players;
```

here is the method that defines "index"

```
-(id)initWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
if (self == [super init] ) {
    index = indexPath;
}
return self;
}
```

Comment: can you please give the crash report ...it will be helpful to trace

Comment: Can we assume you aren't using ARC? Also, do you have a stack trace? If not, can you enable a breakpoint on exceptions and run this with the debugger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`indexPath` is an object, not a struct, so it will be deallocated if you don't take ownership of it. You should be able to fix this issue as such:

```
-(id)initWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  if( (self == [super init]) ) {
    index = [indexPath retain]; // need to take ownership of this
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
  // include all your regular -dealloc code
  [index release];
  [super dealloc];
}
```

Also, with these kinds of memory issues, it's purely coincidence that you see the error with iOS 5. It didn't work under iOS 4 either, you've just been lucky.

Comment: instead of [indexPath retain] , we may use self.index = indexPath

Comment: @Ali3n according to the code posted in his question, index is not a property of the class, so you can't set `self.index`.

Comment: Thanks @JasonCoco, that worked perfectly! Can you point me to any reference materiel on structs vs. objects?

Comment: @UtkarshShah well, structs are just standard C structs and objects are Objective-C objects. Almost everything used with the Objective-C frameworks are objects with the following common exceptions: the geometry primitives (e.g., CGRect, CGPoint, etc), NSRange, and affine transforms. You can take a look at the NSValue class additions' documentation for common structs used by the various frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you initialize the Players array anywhere? If you didn't, that would cause the bad access.

Comment: I did, thanks for answering though! See @JasonCoco's answer for the solution.